# How to call Search Dialog by click on a common button

Tags: android

I created a Search Interface in Android. when we click on hardware search button our own search Dialog pops up. like this tutorial : http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/search-interface/

Then I made a action bar 
( http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html)
and I put a search button on it. I want to load my search Dialog when I click on the button.(The same when I click on hardware search button on the phone)

I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have called method onSearchRequested() before successfully. What Ion suggested may work also.

See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29

Comment: Yes, That's what I exactly needed : onSearchRequested(), Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

The answer is inside the second like you gave:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_search:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tapped search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Just extend the activity with the actionbar with ActionBarActivity and override this method.

Comment: Yes you are right, but basically I would laod the search box. That was my question. You can see the right answer by eyespyus. Thanks